# Stub a Http4s 0.20.x Client for testing

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s

I'd like to test that a Http4s `Client` is being called from my class `ClassUnderTest` (to make a HTTP request) and that the request made contains the headers I expect.

In **0.18.x**, I did something like below. Using a side effect to store the value of the headers so that I can make an assertion after the call. In the example below, `f.execute(...)` is expected to make a `PUT` with the `client` instance and I'm trying to record all request handling and storing the headers.

```scala
  "Request has headers" >> {

    var headers = List[String]()

    val client = Client[IO](new Kleisli[IO, Request[IO], DisposableResponse[IO]](request => {
      headers = request.headers.map(_.name.toString()).toList
      Ok().map(DisposableResponse(_, IO.pure(())))
    }), IO.pure(()))

    val f = ClassUnderTest(client)
    f.execute("example")

    headers must_== List(
      "Content-Type",
      "X-Forwarded-For",
      "Content-Length"
    )
  }
```

The real code is [here](https://github.com/tobyweston/temperature-machine/blob/cae33c941d867094a6a792a25e16d95c3d0dec7f/src/test/scala/bad/robot/temperature/client/HttpUploadTest.scala) if you're interested.

`ClassUnderTest` took a `Client[IO]` so I could get the above working.

```scala
class ClassUnderTest(client: http4s.Client[IO])
```

In Http4s **0.20.12**, I had to change the signature to:

```scala
class ClassUnderTest(client: Resource[IO, http4s.Client[IO]])
```

...and now I can't figure out how to stub out the client for tests. I experimented with `JavaNetClientBuilder` but that doesn't help because I can get an instance of `Client` (after `.create`) and now I need a `Resource[IO, http4s.Client[IO]]`.

**How can I use a test double to stand in for the `Client` / `Resource[F, Client[F]]` so that I can test the requests it makes?**

The [testing page](https://http4s.org/v0.20/testing/) on the docs doesn't really help me. I want a test double, not to test all the functionality of the `Service` (I don't want to startup a server).

Comment: I would suggest that you should look at what a [`Resource`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/resource.html) is first. Maybe you can figure something out from there.

Comment: What makes you say you "had to change the signature" in that way? Using a `Resource` of a `Client` implies you are likely creating and destroying `Client`s whenever you want to use them which is expensive and inefficient. You can use `use` to do effects using a resource and, in principle, that `use` block could contain your entire program.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67258167/3726554